# check and update nested documents in mongoose mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, updates

i am new in mongodb and mongoose and i don't know how i can change an object in array which is in other object .
here is simple version of my schema

```
const shiftSchema = new Schema({
phone: String,
order: {
    startTime: String,
    finishTime: String,
    orders: [{
        stat: boolean,
        orderId: Number
       }]
}
});
```

orderId is actually the time every 5 so first object in orders has startTime+5 value as orderId and the last one has  finishTime value.

so now i want to find the doc that has for example 0911111 as phone , 04090405 as startTime , 04090900 as finishTime , and inside it i want to update just the object that it's orderId is 04090435 if it's stat was false and also update 2 objects before it . which are 04090430 and 04090425 and also check their stat to be false and if even one of these 3 objects has true stat do not update it and send error.

i know it has answered many times but i can't find any solution for mine in specific conditions ,so please help me.

Note: i know that for updating this kind of arrays i can do something like this :

```
Shift.updateOne({
    'order.orders': {$elemMatch: {orderId: {$lte: start}, stat: "true"}}
}, {
    '$set': {'order.orders.$.stat': 'ready'}
})
```

but it just update whole Shift Collection but i only just want to update one doc.

All tips will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: You didn't filter on the `phone` field in the query part.

Comment: @joe i know, because the query is for another work and i just mentioned it to show that this code didn't work for this condition and i need something else.